# Custom the backgroud of a UIButton or UIBarButtonItem on segControl & bars

Tags: ios, background, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to change the appearance of my UIButtons int the view as well as UIBarButtonItems in the NaviBar or toolBar or SegControl.

And here are 2 questions.

NO.1. How can I set customed background pictures to the buttons I mentioned while I can change their titles programmaticly? I mean I found that if I set the background of a button, the title seems to be concealed by the background image?

NO.2. I tried to add the text of the title directly on the png, ( which is actually a imperfect way since I need to change the title during the runtime). Anyway it works out both the image and the text,  but the resolution seems to be reduced because the text became sort of blurred.

Can anyone give me some advices how to achieve it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NO.1` The button title should not be obscured by the background image. Are you setting the button's image in code like this:

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

?  You may be instead setting the button's image property (which is different from its background image).

`NO.2` You really don't want to be adding text to the button PNG, for the exact reason you mention. Buttons in iOS are designed to display images and text the way you want - put your energy into getting the built-in buttons working the way they should. There are umpteen billion tutorials out there about how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I was using [button setImage: ...] so that the title won't appear. I am now going to try change the segControl's look, thanks again for instructing me, I am really sort of a green hand on IOS.

Comment: Thanks! I was using [button setImage: ...] so that the title won't appear. I am now going to try change the segControl's look, thanks again for instructing me, I am really sort of a green hand on IOS.

Comment: You're welcome! You're welcome! I assume this isn't Brian Eno?

Comment: Haha, almost, actually my girlfriend is such a big fan of Brian Eno that she asks me to use this as my name everywhere, =.=

Comment: I actually traded emails with him for a couple of weeks a few years ago, about some music software that I was working on. Cool guy.

Comment: Wow, that's also really cool for you! Being in contact with such a famous person. So I guess maybe you are famous too? :P

Comment: Definitely not - famous people usually don't feel the need to name-drop. Also, Eno's not all *that* famous - most people have heard his name because he shows up in crossword puzzles a lot.